# Click a button using selenium

Tags: python, selenium

Here is the code for the button

```
<li class="selected ng-binding" ng-bind="text.loginLink">Click Me</li>
```

How can I click this type of button. I have tried

```
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//li[contains(text(),"Click Me")]')
```

but it is not working. What can I do ?

Comment: After looking at your code one of the solution for this would be  xpath = //span[.='Click Me'], I assume that button name is Click Me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this xpath :

```
//span[contains(text(),"Click Me")]
```

Comment: button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[contains(text(),'Click Me')]') is giving invalid syntax

Comment: Try this : `driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[contains(text(),"Click Me")]')`

Comment: Add your xpath in double quote like, button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Click Me')]")

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//li[contains(text(),'Click Me')]").click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below xpaths, if not please provide the html source for the parent element's as well.

```
//li[.='Click Me']

//li[contains(text(),'Click Me')]

//li[@ng-bind="text.loginLink"]
```